# How can i get data from _forward() helper in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using _forward() helper to pass an array from one to another action.. but i don't know how can i access this array in my receiving action.. here is the _forward() helper i am using

```
$this->_forward('action', 'controller', 'null', $Myarray);
```

is this correct and how can i access this $Myarray in my another action of same controller

Comment: The third param have no need of the '...'. You have to use null instead.
After that...can you give us more details about $err_array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to `_forward()` a request to another controller/action, you would access the params you passed by calling `$this->getRequest()->getParam('param');` from the controller action that was the handler for the forward.

Example:

```
// in IndexController testAction
$myarray = array(
    'param1' => 'value1',
    'param2' => 'value2'
);
$this->_forward('forward-test', 'Test', null, $myarray);

// In TestController forwardTestAction
$value1 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param1', '');
$value2 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param2', '');
```

If `$Myarray` is not an array with key-value pairs or you want to access it from a single parameter, you would want to set the 4th parameter of `_forward()` to something like `array('myarrayparam' => $Myarray)` and then receive it with `$this->getRequest()->getParam('myarrayparam', array());`